# Redmi Note 7 factory reset via PC

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, hardware, rom, xiaomi

I was just trying to flash Lineage OS on my new Redmi Note 7, since MIUI kinda sucks, and it didn't really seem to work. So after a few tries and restarts, my phone started requesting the password for an email address I entered into my lock screen when I first got the phone, in case I'd ever lose it and someone would find the person could message me. But as it turns out, the m in my email address' .com is missing and the phone keeps asking for the email's password to start Android instead of the usual PIN code.

I figured I should just try wiping it completely, but after a lot of wasted time and energy, I still haven't found a method to factory reset it. Please help, I know this is a very specific issue, but maybe there is someone here who could just help me out.

Comment: https://www.getdroidtips.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-7-stock-firmware

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Stock Recovery, 
Reboot into recovery and choose Wipe Data(Factory Reset).

If you're on TWRP Recovery, 
Reboot into recovery and select Wipe -> Swipe to Factory Reset.

EDIT: The FRP lock usually gets nuked when flashed under EDL mode, refer to your device forums about booting your phone to EDL mode, usually this will require jumping contacts in the motherboard while connecting phone to the PC, be careful with that.

Comment: the problem is the FRP lock (factory reset protection) so this answer is partially helpful (depending on TWRP's fstab it may possible to wipe FRP)

Comment: even more worse it has 2x FRP (Mi account + google account) https://gsmrakesh.blogspot.com/2019/05/redmi-note-7-frp-and-mi-account-unlock.html